# Ten minutes to deploy a wepapp

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager, octopus

I have deployed a web app creating a new resource group using Azure templates triggering from Octopus. 10 minutes for ab empty web app is long time frame. What does this mean ? How can I debug the process ? We are building a Continuous deployment system where time matters a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at the deployment steps to see what part takes the most time? In azure portal, go to ththe resource group, deployments and it should show you how long each arm step took - what is the longest?

Comment: I had another thought - are you using dependsOn or reference resources form each other? if there are dependencies then resources need to be deployed before the dependant ones can be (obviously) so if you have dpeendencies you dont need that can slow deploys down considerably

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to make a separate deployment for the web-app resource and the application it self. The application can use slots in the web-app so you will be able to put it to production without downtime. There is no need to redeploy the web-app resource every time.

Comment: We are redeploying as we want to build a continuous deployment pipeline. The reason we are deploying the infrastructure is we are also versioning and doing a network swap. Thought about using the deployment slots. The down side is they live on the same resource and it we really do not want to risk those resources. The stackoverflow error in staging slot could lock the main application.

Comment: What if you want to update the resources later, then you want to do a redeployment. You do not have to use the staging slot to do any testing on or make it a public url if you fear errors. I have never heard form an application on a staging slot that kill the production applications.

Comment: I want to have a clean blue/green deployment where I know that everything has been upgraded to a new operating system. And the whole process is working clearly. Reusing the same resource is not my first choice.

Comment: Peter I guess I want to go to the pets versus cattle route. As the when we get new resources we are at least sure that we have the upgrades and we are not moving with our legacy systems.

Comment: Reference https://www.slideshare.net/randybias/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle-and-using-it-properly

Comment: Making a 2 stage pipeline does not make your resources pets. Managing your resource by hand makes them pets. Managing them from ci/cd pipelines makes them cattle